# TSLint does not complain about missing imports

Tags: typescript, tslint

TSLint does not complain about missing imports (It is not ok with me leaving `console.log` statements in the code, however). Linter says there is no problem with my code, but it does not compile. How to I configure TSLint to complain about missing import issues?

This is my TSLint configuration:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:latest", "tslint-react", "tslint-react-hooks", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "rulesDirectory": [],
  "rules": {
    "max-line-length": {
      "options": [120]
    },
    "new-parens": true,
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-conditional-assignment": true,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "no-console": {
      "severity": "warning",
      "options": ["debug", "log", "time", "timeEnd", "trace"]
    },
    "interface-name": false,
    "no-empty-interface": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "no-namespace": false,
    "no-submodule-imports": false,
    "no-implicit-dependencies": false,
    "variable-name": false,
    "no-conditional-assignment": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "only-arrow-functions": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-bitwise": false,
    "ban-types": {
      "options": []
    },
    "typedef": true,
    "prefer-for-of": false,
    "no-duplicate-imports": false,
    "no-empty": { "severity": "warning" },
    "no-require-imports": { "severity": "warning" },
    "no-var-requires": { "severity": "warning" }
  },
  "jsRules": {
    "max-line-length": {
      "options": [120]
    },
    "no-console": {
      "severity": "warning",
      "options": ["debug", "log", "time", "timeEnd", "trace"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When your typescript complains about the missing imports, it's more than enough.

Comment: @htn I would also like to see these kinds of problems when commiting my code to the Git repository, though...

Comment: If you are linting automatically for each commit, you just need to add a compilation in the process.

Comment: @htn But what about navigating the errors? SublimeLinter has this functionality, and I really like it. The problem is though, that it does not report type/variable/module not found errors.

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason is you or the lib `declare` what your import content in the somewhere like `.d.ts`. in this case the typescript type system can not complain about it if you did not import because it maybe the global one.